# vue emit data back to parent when using a slot

Tags: vue.js

I have input on custom component and when i click on the next button on the wrapper component i need to emit details to the parent component.

How is this possible in vue?

wrapper.vue

```
<template>
    <div :id="contentId" class="mt-3">    
    <div>        
        <slot></slot>        
    </div>
    <b-row class="float-right">                
                <b-col>
                    <button cssClass="e-outline" v-on:click="btnNext">{{nextButtonText}}</button>  
                </b-col> 
            </b-row>     
    </div>

    </template>
```

parent.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Wrapper contentId="1">
            <CustomComponent1 />
        </wrapper>
        <Wrapper contentId="2">
            <CustomComponent1 />
        </wrapper>
    </div>
    </template>
```

customComponent1.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="name" />
<input v-model="name2" />
    </div>
</template>
```

code above is for illustrative purposes.

Comment: are you trying to have the _wrapper_ emit data that is in the _CustomComponent`_?

Comment: Yes that's what I want. Would it be better to just move the button to the slot?

Comment: You would need to make the data accessible to the wrapper. you can do that using $emit and slot-scope

Comment: Ok thanks would you be able to provide example as in how that would apply to my example? I have read the docs on slot scope but for a novice it's not that easy to follow.

Comment: it's a very confusing concept, IMHO. I'm writing up an answer, but you can see a working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/0pzjm7vo5n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the wrapper doesn't innately have access to data of the scoped component, therefore these links have to be created manually. There is no way to tell how many children or slots the component may have, so this kind of functionality is not part of the vue magic.

So in an example where you have parent `App` component, which holds a `Wrapper` that has a `MyInput` component in the slot...

### MyInput

The `MyInout` component doesn't automatically update other components, so it needs to be setup to `$emit` the internal data.

This can be done using a `watch`, `@change` listener for the input, or some other way. You can emit multiple datum as they change, or use a single payload with all the data

```js
this.$emit("input", myData);
```

### App

The `App` needs to explicitly connect the data between `MyInout` and `Wrapper`

```html
<Wrapper> <MyInput @input="onInput" slot-scope="{ onInput }" /> </Wrapper>
```

*The magic/trick happens here, where we bind the `input` emit function of the input to the `onInput` function using slot-scope.*

### Wrapper

The wrapper then needs to listen to the events passed (via `App`) from `Wrapper`

```html
<slot :onInput="onInput" />
```

where `onInput` is a method that would process the data

see example below
[image: Edit Vue Template]

I would recommend the following reading

- https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4332 (specifically Evan's response why it's not possible)
- https://adamwathan.me/renderless-components-in-vuejs/ Adam has a thoroughly documented way of using render functions and slots to abstract functionality from the UI. While it's not directly related, it's a worthwhile read and may provide more info on using slot-scope as well as some perspective on improving the structure of UI components.

Comment: thanks so much - it has helped me in my project. Your example is simple and along with your explanation shows the feature in a way that is easy to understand.

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing, but using Vue 2.6 and v-slots but I can't seem to get things to work properly. Could you provide an example? I'm sort of grasping at straws here. Thanks

Comment: if this doesn't answer your question, you may need to open up a new question with your specific issues/code/etc. Having a minimal (not)working example on sandbox ready will help get your question resolved faster.

Comment: Actually, it does answer my question. It's just that since slot-scope are now deprecated, I wanted to know how to implement your solution using Vue's new syntax.

Comment: I was able to solve it actually. you have to put the v-slot directive on the <wrapper> tag instead of the <MyInput> tag and it'll work.

Comment: @Osuwariboy I trying this approach (put the v-slot directive inside parent tag) but unsuccessful. How you solve it?